# How to use Sitemap for webcrawling in Java?

Tags: java, web-crawler

I need to develop the crawler which will crawl all the product link and price from a site . I heard that its more efficient and fast to use Sitemap which is mention in robots.txt file but I am not able to figured out how to use sitemap for crawling. please someone help me how to use Sitemap to crawl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you said you want to create a crawler and you want to use the sitemap available on robots.txt then here is what you need to do.

1) Any site will have its robots.txt on there first level of site. So for any website you want to crawl you can parse 
**`http://any-websitesite-name.com/robots.txt`** for **`Sitemap:`**
You can write a parser in Java.Example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=87

2) Once done you will get the sitemap url (can be either a .xml or a .xml.gz)

3) Write a Java digester to parse the xml. Here is an example: http://devguru.com/features/tutorials/jakarta/jakarta.asp
Make sure you read the `<loc>..</loc>` tag for any URL

NB: Many website wont have there sitemap URL on robots.txt.. better to hit `http://website-name/sitemap.xml` when its not available on robots.txt.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your useful comments. Is there any open source which is using sitemap technique for crawling. And my need is to get the specified Item link sitemap contain all types of item how to get the particular item link suppose I need only watch link from http://www.newegg.com/ .. please suggest me .Thanks again

Comment: do you mean opens source java code to parse the sitemap xml? If you need product update best way is to use the RSS rather then using sitemap. Eg: http://www.newegg.com/RSS/Index.aspx. click on any category. Get the rss and parse it with Java.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please help me to get the RSS feed link. How will I know the RSS index link for any site. Thanks sooo much for frequent reply...

Comment: for example if I want to know the link of RSS index for http://www.amazon.com/ site how will I know.

Comment: Its a more of a manual process to know rss feed for a site. Usually there will be links in site pointing to the rss feed. example for amazon: http://www.amazon.com/rss/tag/books/new/ref=tag_rsh_hl_ersn   You can change "books" in the URL to some other valid stuffs like say "gadgets" or "nokia" or "apple" etc what ever is relevant for you.

Answer (score 0):

To use a sitemap you have to have one before so you need to generate it first. Googlebot and others will then use your generated sitemap to index it for search engines. There are several free sitemap generators, for example http://www.xml-sitemaps.com but they have limitations.

AFAIK it doesn't really have to do much with Java. I mean, you can create a crawler fairly easily with Java but I don't thik it's worth it. Free versions do their job well if the site isn't too big.

Comment: **Hi please someone help me to figured out which Open Source is using the Sitemap for crawling . **

Comment: Cannot really understand the question. Did you mix up some of the definitions? Open Source is just a (software) development practice.

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt provides exclusion list and is used to alert cralwer respecting exclusion to refrain from mentioned directories. Not all sites provide exclusion. Site map helps better know categorization of products & hence is useful.